# Taking a subset of a main dataset based on the values of another data frame that is a subset of the main data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have these two datasets : `df` as the main data frame and `g` as a created data frame

```
df = data.frame(x = seq(1,20,2),y = letters[1:10] )
df

g = data.frame(xx = c(2,3,4,5,7,8,9) )
```

and I want to take a subset of the data frame `df` based on the values xx of the data frame `g` as follows

```
m = df[df$x==g$xx,]
```

but the result is based on the match between the two data frames for the order of the matched values. not the matched values themselves.

output

```
> m
  x y
2 3 b
```

I don't what the error I am making.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to use `%in%` instead of `==`

```
> df[df$x %in% g$xx,]
  x y
2 3 b
3 5 c
4 7 d
5 9 e
```

You can also use `inner_join` from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  inner_join(g, by = c("x" = "xx"))
```

`intersect` can be useful too

```
df[intersect(df$x, g$xx),]
```

Answer (score 2):

using `merge`

```
 merge(df, g, by.x = "x", by.y = 'xx')
  x y
1 3 b
2 5 c
3 7 d
4 9 e
```